# Sum over cells across different files in Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'd like to do a sum or sumprod over cells across different files. More precisely:

I have a list of file paths to other .ods files which contain data organized in the exact same way. Say in cell A1 `'file:///C:/Users/jean__000/Desktop/data1.ods'#$Sheet1`, ..., in cell A9 `'file:///C:/Users/jean__000/Desktop/data9.ods'#$Sheet1`). In cells B1, ... , B9 I have a boolean representing whether I want the corresponding files to be included in the calculations or not. I now want to compute the sum, over all files which are set to TRUE, of a given cell (say, C1). If this was just a sum across sheets I could use a sumprod of indirect of the given range, but I can't find how to designate a range across different files.

I could add a new column (say C), and have `data1.ods#$Sheet1.C1` appear in C1, ... , `data9.ods#$Sheet1.C1` appear in C9 ; and then sumprod over that, but I'd like to avoid creating useless columns.

This is a follow-up question from [Replicate data from separate files in OpenOffice Calc](https://superuser.com/questions/1047631/replicate-data-from-separate-files-in-openoffice-calc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single formula that works:

```
=SUM(IF($B$1,INDIRECT($A$1 & ".C1"),0), IF($B$2,INDIRECT($A$2 & ".C1"),0))
```

This handles the first two files.  For more files, add another `IF` clause for each file.

However I think it would be easier to create "useless columns" and then [SUMIF](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function) them.  Using additional cells for calculations is what spreadsheets are designed for.

Comment: I do not want to do it by hand, if I get 20 or 100 files, the formula is going to be ugly. Adding columns would work, but it means for every calculation I make I need to add a column. Is there really no other way?

Comment: Are you interested in solutions that require some macro programming, or that use OpenOffice Base?  Both of those provide more powerful methods of handling information.

Comment: I don't know anything about either, I'll have a look. Basically, before I knew Sumprod I would create a useless colum and sum over that, I was hoping the situation here wa similar. Cheers.